# sort Select Options elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with sorting my select list elements.. In fact I have two dependent lists one with a list of "models" which I have sorted successfully using this function:

```
var sel = $('#model');
var opts_list = sel.find('option');
opts_list.sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1; });
sel.html('').append(opts_list);
```

But the second list contains the versions of the chosen model with the build number between brackets...

Examples:

```
 2.00.312 (11)  
 5.105.402 (43)
 2.05.105 (141)
 4.54.200 (151)
 2.35.504 (61)
 1.204.454 (10)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9hdaqpv/

Comment: Please make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: extract number in brackets using regex str.match(/\((.*?)\)/g); then use the same sort logic

Comment: @lonut: I just added the jsfiddle to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a regex made the job:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j7sarzmc/)

```
items[value].sort(function (a, b) {
    a = Object.keys(a)[0].replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/,"").replace(/\./g,"");
    b = Object.keys(b)[0].replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/,"").replace(/\./g,"");
    console.log(a,b);
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I just checked and it's not really sorted :/

Comment: what you mean?? so prob i ven't understood your question... you want to order by the numbers inside the brackets right??

Comment: Oh! no no not at all I want to sort by the version number essentially excuses me

Comment: oh sorry... now its ok